# search does not yield access restricted results

Tags: search, user-access, membership, logging

If the user is logged out and tries to search something, he is redirected to the login page. How is it possible to have the search always show all of the results (including the excerpts and the image), even if the user is logged out and the resulting pages/posts are restricted to members only?
I tried using the plugin "WordPress Access Control", but that did not help.

Comment: How exactly are restrictions implemented?

Comment: I am using the groups plugin, and setting capabilities and groups, along with swiftype search plugin

Comment: also I tried using another search plugin (relevanssi) and the results are now showing, but I would like to use swiftype instead. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setting the posts to private in WordPress, you can add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
function include_private_in_search( $query ) {
  // not an admin page and is the main query
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
     $query->set( 'post_status', array ( 'publish', 'private' ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_private_in_search' );
```

Then you can format the search results page to show the excerpt and image.

Comment: Are you sure this works? ["Private" posts are heavily protected.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2970)

Comment: I have tried setting the posts to private, but then they do not appear at all at certain lists of posts I'm showing...

Comment: @S_ha_dum I just tested it again and it is working for me.

Comment: @vobs Try creating a page that runs that a specific query like `query_posts('post_status=private');` and see if that works for you.